# Writing to a socket from different threads (a concurrent UDP server in Haskell)

Tags: multithreading, sockets, haskell, server, udp

**EDIT:**

I'm writing an UDP BitTorrent tracker in Haskell. The state is based on STM (two TVar Maps) passed in my datatype ServerState into *runUDPServer*, *acceptConnections*, *handleConnection* and *handleRequestData*. The clients will either request starting a "connection", announce or scrape. Every time someone sends the server a message, they're supposed to get a message back. (The protocol is here: http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/udp_tracker_protocol.html).

I will do some binary parsing, some processing in the IO monad (just STM really) and send a message encoded in binary back to the sender. Initially, I was thinking that I could just run every request like this in its own thread, but I guess I could just fork a few threads and let them do the work instead. One problem with that might be that the whole server (all threads) would be blocked by n people sending UDP packages really slowly (but maybe that's not actually possible).

I think I could define my question more clearly thus: **if I just fork n threads that all run handleConnection simultaneously, will that mess with the socket somehow? Also, (how) could I ideally somehow spawn a new thread for each received packet?**

I mean, when I fork a few threads and write to stdout, the output will be garbled / a mixture between what was printed from the separate threads. *Network.accept* actually provides a handle and the individual threads don't really need to know about the socket, but I can't use *accept*. **I wouldn't just assume that it's safe to write to a socket from multiple threads simultaneously.**

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Exception (bracket)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Network.Socket as S hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import qualified Network.Socket.ByteString as S

runUDPServer serverState port =
    S.withSocketsDo $ bracket (createSocket port) S.close (acceptConnections serverState)

    where
        createSocket port = do
            serverAddr <- fmap head $ S.getAddrInfo
                (Just (S.defaultHints {S.addrFlags = [S.AI_PASSIVE]}))
                Nothing
                (Just port)

            socket <- S.socket (S.addrFamily serverAddr) S.Datagram S.defaultProtocol
            S.bind socket $ S.addrAddress serverAddr

            return socket

        acceptConnections serverState socket = do
            handleConnection serverState socket
            acceptConnections socket

        handleConnection serverState socket = do
            (requestData, remoteAddress) <- S.recvFrom socket 2048
            responseData <- handleRequestData serverState requestData remoteAddress
            S.sendTo socket responseData remoteAddress

        handleRequestData :: ServerState -> BS.ByteString -> S.SockAddr -> IO BS.ByteString
        handleRequestData serverState requestData remoteAddress = do
            putStrLn "-----"

            putStrLn $ "Received UDP message"
            putStrLn $ "Address: " ++ show remoteAddress

            -- (left out code here)
            return "Dummy ByteString"
```

I would be very grateful for any tips, pointers etc.

Comment: "I'd rather not have a pool of threads each running recvFrom, but I guess I could. I'm not sure how I would write to the socket from multiple threads in a sensible way though." Why not? That all should be atomic on posix, right? If so you can just `replicateM n (forkIO $ forever $ handleConnection socket)`. I don't know if there are performance implications to contention on a UDP socket. If so it might be faster to have one thread reading data and shuttling it into a blocking FIFO queue.

Comment: @jberryman Instead of a pool of threads, you could instead dynamically create threads, one for each connection.

Comment: This question does not contain enough information for a complete answer. For example, do you want to collect the information provided by all clients somewhere? Do you need to collect them by client? Did you verify that your current approach isn't fast/"concurrent" enough? Is UDP correct for your use case?

Comment: @jberryman If that's atomic on POSIX, that's great news. I'll try it out.

Comment: @Zeta I've edited the question, I hope it's clearer now. Yes, I'm collecting things like IP addresses as well as the actual requests. No, I'm not sure if I need to make the server faster than it currently is, but I'm doing this project to learn how to work with Haskell and multithreading, among other things, so I kind of want to try out that approach. UDP is the protocol I need to support.

Comment: @PyRulez how? I guess I could run forkIO AFTER having read data from the socket, but that would mean using a single thread for reading requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn some concurrency bro!

First thing you need to learn is [`forkIO :: IO () -> IO ThreadId`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO). This is where all the concurrency starts. You give it an IO action, and it starts a thread to run that IO action, like magic man! Everything, including that `accept` thing you were talking about, goes back to `forkIO`! Since Haskell data is immutable, it's perfectly safe to use (if you don't use locks, no problem (and then deadlock is impossible).)

The rest of learning concurrency in Haskell is how to use `forkIO`, and libraries based on `forkIO` (and some related primitives.) First, read [`Control.Concurrent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Concurrent.html). Then read [Parallel and Concurrent Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929) (free ebook). To get a feel for how the book helps your situation, go to [Chapter 12](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch12.html).

Haskell is *much* **much** ***much*** better at dealing with concurrency than any imperative and/or impure language, unless specifically built for concurrency (cue downvotes from non-Haskellers). Embrace it.

---

Okay, for this, you would use some sort of channel. `MVar` would actually be sufficient (as long as you are writing faster than you are producing). See [this](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_conc-logger). If you produce faster than you write, see [this](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_channels).

The `stm` package has similar constructs.

Comment: as you are talking about `IO` none of the "Haskell is immutable and deadlocks are impossible and much much better" make any sense - you can just *f+++* up as horrible as in any other language here

Comment: @Carsten I said *if you don't use locks* then deadlock is impossible. Sure you can go horribly wrong in Haskell, but you only if you use explicit use mutable variables, and even then, you a lot better of, since you can control what is mutable.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm just unsure about the semantics of simultaneously writing to a socket from multiple threads. Also, the example in the Chapter 12 you linked to uses _Network.accept_.

Comment: @J.F. have one thread accepting connections, but then that thread will fork new ones to handle the handles.

Comment: @PyRulez Well, the problem is that I can't use Network.accept since it only works for TCP. UDP is connectionless. But yes, I could probably build something similar by forking after recvFrom.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd have a single thread for reads, that just called `recv` in a loop, and tossing the requests on to a `Chan` then another for writes, spooling off a `Chan`. However, I actually do suspect, though can't confirm, that you could have multiple threads doing this directly as in your described architecture. The reason I think this may be ok is that IO gets trafficed through the IO manager, which handles multiplexing. While not containing the latest developments, I think the [MIO paper](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/hask035-voellmy.pdf) should cover the basics of how things are currently implemented.